# In a group of $n>20$ people in which some pairs know each other, 20 people are removed. The number of pairs that know each other is $\frac{n-k}{n}$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, graph-theory

Here's the problem:

> In a group of $n>20$ people, there are some (at least one, and possibly all) pairs of people that know each other. (If A knows B, then B knows A). For some $n$ and $k$, this group of people have a property: If any 20 people are removed from the group, the number of pairs of people that know each other is at most $\frac{n-k}{n}$ times that of the original group of people.
> For $k=41$ and $k=39$, for what positive integers $n$ could a group exist?

I'm not quite sure where to start. I tried experimenting with different values of $n$ and various setups, but I'm not making any progress. I also tried representing this using a graph, so that might help anyone who's finding a solution. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

A partial solution:

If you examine the case where all $n$ people know each other, then there are $n\choose 2$ acquaintance pairs. After removing any $20$, there will be $n-20 \choose 2$ acquaintance pairs. So
$$\dfrac {n-20 \choose 2}{n \choose 2}\le \dfrac {n-k}n$$
$$\dfrac{(n-20)(n-21)}{n(n-1)} \le \dfrac {n-k}n$$
$$n^2 - 41n + 420 \le n^2 - (k+1)n + k$$
$$ 420 - k \le (40 - k)n$$
If $40 \le k < 420$, the equation requires a positive value to be $\le$ a non-positive value, which cannot be. But when $k < 40$, we get that if
$$\dfrac{420 - k}{40 - k} \le n$$
then there will be a solution where everyone knows everyone else.

---

But this does not say anything about solutions where some pairs do not know each other.