# Graph Theory Problem with Unknown Vertices and Edges

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

We have a graph with $n$ vertices and $x$ edges where $n>20$ and $1 \leq x \leq \binom{n}{2}$. For some values of $n$ and $k$, the graph is *special*, if and only if when $20$ vertices are removed the number of edges remaining is at most $\frac{n-k}{n} \cdot x$.

a.) If $k = 39$, for what values of $n$ will the graph be *special*?

b.) If $k = 41$, for what values of $n$ will the graph be *special*?

So far I have only been able to compute for the extreme case when everyone knows each other. In this case I wrote:

$\frac{\binom{n-20}{2}}{\binom{n}{2}} \leq \frac{n-k}{n}$ and using algebraic manipulations I got $\frac{420-k}{40-k} \leq n $ which helped me solve for this case, but I have not been able to solve for any other cases besides this one.

Please help me find out how to compute for the $n$ in all the other cases besides the one in which everyone knows each other. A generalized form for the problem would be ideal.

Comment: The [same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3961864/in-a-group-of-n20-people-in-which-some-pairs-know-each-other-20-people-are-r/3962783#3962783) (worded slightly differently) was asked last Saturday. I posted the same case you've solved, but that is as far as it went.

Comment: I'd be curious to know the source, in that case.